# react-native-fbsdk - Share photo error on android

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

When I try to share the photo via Facebook ShareDialog, I receive this error:

> Facebook share fail with error: Error: Unsupported scheme for media
>   Uri : data

For converting the image to blob I use react-native-fetch-blob
Facebook share works well on iOS. I even tried to hardcode the dataUri with the one generated on the iOS device.

Versions:

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.48.0",
"react-native-fbsdk": "0.6.3",
"react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
```

**Code snippets.**

Convert to dataurl:

```
toDataURL(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', url)
      .then((res) => {
        let base64Str = res.base64();
        base64Str = 'data:image/jpg;charset=utf-8;base64,' + base64Str;
        resolve(base64Str);
      })
      .catch((errorMessage, statusCode) => {
        reject(errorMessage);
      })
    });
}
```

Share:

```
if (attachments.length) {
  let attachmentsPromises = attachments.map(a => {
    return this.toDataURL(a.url);
  });

  Promise.all(attachmentsPromises).then(res => {
    let shareContent = {
      contentType: "photo",
      contentUrl: "http://www.google.com",
      contentDescription: text,
      quote: text,
      photos: res.map(dataUrl => {
        return {
          caption: text,
          imageUrl: dataUrl,
          userGenerated: true
        };
      })
    };

    shareWithFacebook(shareContent);
  });
} else {
  let shareContent = {
    contentType: "link",
    contentUrl: "http://www.google.com",
    quote: text
  };
  shareWithFacebook(shareContent);
}

function shareWithFacebook(shareContent) {
  console.log('sharing on facebook', shareContent);
  ShareDialog.canShow(shareContent)
    .then(function(canShow) {
      console.log('canshow', canShow);
      if (canShow) {
        return ShareDialog.show(shareContent);
      } else {
        onSuccess();
      }
    })
    .then((result) => {
      if (result && result.isCanceled) {
        alert("Facebook share cancelled");
      } 
      onSuccess();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert("Facebook share fail with error: " + error);
      onSuccess();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `react-native-fbsdk` does not support `Base64` data for now.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/faq#faq_631338030360975

Actually it can be handled [over here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/9c63f00a849de685ccae73f57b79ec12a760d53a/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/Utility.java#L178). `buildSharePhoto` method is used for to convert coming JS data into `SharePhoto` object.